# How can I scroll a half page on C-v and M-v?

Tags: spacemacs, scrolling

I use Spacemacs, and for some time I've rebound <kbd>C-v</kbd> and <kbd>M-v</kbd> to `spacemacs/scroll-half-page-down` and `spacemacs/scroll-half-page-up`, respectively, to aid my understanding of the buffer as I move through it.

After a recent update, though, these functions seem to no longer be defined. How can I get them back, or something reasonably similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually managed to find the equivalent functions. They are

- `View-scroll-half-page-forward`
- `View-scroll-half-page-backward`

So, I've updated my dotfile's user-config section to contain

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'View-scroll-half-page-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-v") 'View-scroll-half-page-backward)
```

and this seems to work fine!

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, View-scroll-half-page-forward`

Comment: @ShaneCreighton-Young You need to add `(autoload 'View-scroll-half-page-forward "view")
(autoload 'View-scroll-half-page-backward "view")` to your init file. This will load the needed view library when you use those commands.

Comment: @clemera That works! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I personally recommend you to use a package named `golden-ratio-scroll-screen`.
You can add melpa to your package-list if you have not.

> (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" .
>   "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

and then `M-x package-list-packages`,
search for `golden-ratio-`,

or go to https://github.com/jixiuf/golden-ratio-scroll-screen
to get it.

It will do the following two things, which are to me excellent, maybe also what you want:

1. Scroll half screen down or up, and
2. highlight current line before or after scrolling.

Comment: wow this is an amazing little package :) I actually like this more than default behaviour of scroll-up and scroll-down

Comment: Personally I like to highlight the bottom/top line shortly and after that the new position after the scroll, see my [blog](https://with-emacs.com/posts/keep-scrollin-scrollin-scrollin/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write pretty simple elisp code to achieve this :-

```
(defun scroll-half-page-down ()
  "scroll down half the page"
  (interactive)
  (scroll-down (/ (window-body-height) 2)))

(defun scroll-half-page-up ()
  "scroll up half the page"
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up (/ (window-body-height) 2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
(defun advice/scroll-context (proc &rest r)
  (let ((next-screen-context-lines (/ (window-text-height) 2)))
    (apply proc r)))

(mapc
 (lambda (sym) (advice-add sym :around #'advice/scroll-context))
 '(scroll-up scroll-down image-scroll-up image-scroll-down))
```

in my emacs.el profile to achive this.